# Python Tkinter wrap widgets in frame if they reach the end of the screen

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

Is there something like pack to new line for Tk geometry manager? I am using pack to put widgets inside of a frame. On a high resolution screen, the widgets fit find side by side. However, if you put it into a smaller screen, the widgets will run out of room in the frame.

Basically, we go from:

[image: Before]

to:

[image: after]

You can see how it cuts off of my Processors entry field. The relevant code:

```
options_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(
        parent_frame, text="Blast Options")
options_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, expand=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self._set_up_blast_options(options_frame)

def _set_up_blast_options(self, options_frame):
    self.evalue = Tkinter.DoubleVar()
    self.evalue.set(1)
    self.word_size = Tkinter.IntVar()
    self.word_size.set(4)
    self.penalty_mismatch = Tkinter.DoubleVar()
    self.penalty_mismatch.set(-4)
    self.min_d_match = Tkinter.IntVar()
    self.min_d_match.set(5)
    self.proc_count = Tkinter.IntVar()
    self.proc_count.set(cpu_count())

    # evalue
    e_value_label = ttk.LabelFrame(
        options_frame, text="e-Value Threshold")
    e_value_entry = ttk.Entry(e_value_label)
    e_value_entry.insert(0, self.evalue.get())
    e_value_entry.bind('<Return>', self._validate_e_value)
    e_value_entry.bind('<FocusOut>', self._validate_e_value)
    e_value_label.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, pady=5, padx=5, fill=X)
    e_value_entry.pack(side=TOP, expand=1, pady=5, padx=5, fill=X)

    # word size
    word_size_label = ttk.LabelFrame(
        options_frame, text="Word Size")
    word_size_entry = ttk.Entry(word_size_label)
    word_size_entry.insert(0, self.word_size.get())
    word_size_entry.bind('<Return>', self._validate_word_value)
    word_size_entry.bind('<FocusOut>', self._validate_word_value)
    word_size_label.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, pady=5, padx=5, fill=X)
    word_size_entry.pack(side=TOP, expand=1, pady=5, padx=5, fill=X)

    penalty_mismatch_label = ttk.LabelFrame(
        options_frame, text="Penalty Mismatch")
    penalty_mismatch_entry = ttk.Entry(penalty_mismatch_label)
    penalty_mismatch_entry.insert(0, self.penalty_mismatch.get())
    penalty_mismatch_entry.bind(
        '<Return>', self._validate_penalty_mismatch_value)
    penalty_mismatch_entry.bind(
        '<FocusOut>', self._validate_penalty_mismatch_value)
    penalty_mismatch_label.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, pady=5,
                                padx=5, fill=X)
    penalty_mismatch_entry.pack(side=TOP, expand=1, pady=5,
                                padx=5, fill=X)
    # Min D Nucleotides
    min_d_match_label = ttk.LabelFrame(
        options_frame, text="Minimal Number of D Nucleotides")
    min_d_match_entry = ttk.Entry(min_d_match_label)
    min_d_match_entry.insert(0, self.min_d_match.get())
    min_d_match_entry.bind(
        '<Return>', self._validate_min_match_value)
    min_d_match_entry.bind(
        '<FocusOut>', self._validate_min_match_value)
    min_d_match_label.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, pady=5, padx=5, fill=X)
    min_d_match_entry.pack(side=TOP, expand=1, pady=5, padx=5, fill=X)

    # how many cpus to use
    proc_count_label = ttk.LabelFrame(
        options_frame, text="Processors")
    proc_count_entry = ttk.Entry(proc_count_label)
    proc_count_entry.insert(0, self.proc_count.get())
    proc_count_entry.bind(
        '<Return>', self._validate_proc_count_value)
    proc_count_entry.bind(
        '<FocusOut>', self._validate_proc_count_value)
    proc_count_label.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, pady=5, padx=5, fill=X)
    proc_count_entry.pack(side=TOP, expand=1, pady=5, padx=5, fill=X)
```

A lot of the event binding and setting of the options may not be relevant, but I thought I should still include...just in case. Would the best option be to switch to a grid manager? The problem there would be this frame is packed inside of another one...and so on. Isn't it that if you start using the grid manager, you have to use it for everything because you can't mix packed and grid manager in the same frame?

Comment: You can mix pack and grid in the same app -- in fact, it's the recommended thing to do. You just can't mix grid and pack with widgets that have the same parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no inbuilt way of creating dynamic interfaces in tkinter. Your best bet is to get the screen resolution and then grid/pack appropriately.

```
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
get_screensize = (user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1))
```

So for example....

```
widget1 = tkinter.Entry(root,width=20,etc)
widget2 = tkinter.Label(root,text='Hello',etc)
## Now perform update_idletasks() which will force
## Tkinter to calculate their size.
widget1.update_idletasks()
widget2.update_idletasks()
## Now calculate whether they'll fit.
if widget1.winfo_width() + widget2.winfo_width() > screensize[0]:## Not enough space
    widget1.grid(row=0)
    widget2.grid(row=1)
else:## Both will fit on one line.
    widget1.grid(row=0,column=0)
    widget2.grid(row=0,column=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, I agree with I_do_python's answer, but I would make one small modification. I would put all the widgets in a new Frame, and I would use the Frame's width as the litmus test as to whether to wrap. And you can bind an event handler for the `"<Configure>"` event that then checks to see if the Frame's contents need to be wrapped when the application's window (and thus the Frame) is resized.

I had written the below function which uses the grid method to intelligently insert widgets into a frame. It can certainly be improved, but it works for me. Usually if you use `.grid()` to fill a parent, you can get wasted white space when the filling widgets vary in width. The below function addresses this by breaking up the parent into logical columns (`divisions` in the code) and allowing the widgets to span multiple columns. The result is a grid layout with much-reduced wasted white space. The higher you set `divisions`, the better the result, but the default value should work for most situations.

```
def smart_grid(parent, *args, **kwargs): # *args are the widgets!
    divisions   = kwargs.pop('divisions', 100)
    force_f     = kwargs.pop('force', False)
    if 'sticky' not in kwargs:
        kwargs.update(sticky='w')
    try:
        parent.win_width
    except:
        parent.win_width = -1
    winfo_width = parent.winfo_width()
    if 1 < winfo_width != parent.win_width or force_f:
        parent.win_width = winfo_width
        row = col = width = 0
        argc = len(args)
        for i in range(argc):
            widget_width = args[i].winfo_width()
            columns = max(1, int(widget_width * float(divisions) / winfo_width))
            width += widget_width
            if width > winfo_width:
                width = widget_width
                row += 1
                col = 0
            args[i].grid(row=row, column=col, columnspan=columns, **kwargs)
            col += columns
        parent.update_idletasks() # update() # 
        return row + 1
```

Eventually I'll take a few minutes to rewrite it with `w.winfo_reqwidth()` and will update my post.